# Dealing with Whitespaces in url using PHP or codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, urldecode

I am working on a project that requires me to take post code from URL. Since the postcode has got space in it,I have two options to achieve this:
1) Either construct a URL with postcode having a space like this:

```
  http://myhostname/seven/locator/PC1%201LA
```

OR

2) Grab postcode from url and Insert whitespace in the decoded url:

```
 http://myhostname/seven/locator/PC11LA
```

But i am not sure how to do as my Post code could be like this: MM11 5PW       instead PC1 1LA

How can i achieve and sort this problem ?How can i send whitespaces in the url so that it could give me post code like these: MM1 5PW  or PC11 6MP????

NOTE :I am using QR code reader to naviagte to website.The + plus sign is not recognised by the QR reader.

Comment: Use `+` sign instead of `%20`.

Comment: @tereško.I am using QR code reader to naviagte to website.The + plus sign is not recognised by the reader.Any other idea?

Comment: Each country has different post code format (for exampl, Latvia has `LV-0000` format) , which means that, if you cannot use `+` signs, then you will have to use `%20`. There is no way around it.

Comment: use php's urlencode and urldecode

Answer (score 1):

Creating the url with the postcode:

```
<?php

$postCode = 'MM11 5PW';
$url = 'http://myhostname/seven/locator?postcode=' . urlencode($postCode );

?>
```

Somewhere in your locator controller...

```
<?php

$postCode = urldecode($_GET['postcode']);
echo 'Posted postcode: ' . $postCode;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Percent-encoded spaces "%20" work well.

But I'd rather send them inside the query string: `http://hostname/seven/locator?postcode=PC1%201LA`

Comment: Send them as query string? Why?

Comment: But I am using QR code reader to navigate to website.The + or other symbols are not recognised by the reader.